# Search the maximum of a function in R

Tags: r

I have built a function in R, which calculates the value of the density phi of the standard normal. Here it is:

```
f<-function(x){
  v<-1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-0.5*x**2)
  return (v)
}
```

then, I built a sequence of values, and I applied the function f to each of this value:

```
x<-seq(-10,10,length=100)
f(x)
plot(f(x),t="l")
```

Now, I want to demonstrate that the maximum of this function is in 0; how can I do, **using the function** `nlm` ?

Answer (score 2):

As you probably know from reading [the documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/nlm.html), `nlm` performs *minimisation*, not *maximisation*. So you’ll need to wrap it to invert your function’s sign:

```
nlmax = function (f, p, ...) {
    res = nlm(function(x, ...) -f(x, ...), p, ...)
    res$maximum = -res$minimum
    res$minimum = NULL
    res
}
```

Note how we’re inverting two things:

1. The value of the function `f` when invoking `nlm`
2. The resulting estimate of `minimum`.

And now you can run it on your function:

```
nlmax(f, 1)
```

Comment: I enjoyed your answer :)